# Are there any examples of non-computable real numbers?

Tags: computability

Is this true, that if we can describe any (real) number somehow, then it is computable?

For example, $\pi$ is computable although it is irrational, i.e. endless decimal fraction. It was just a luck, that there are some simple periodic formulas to calcualte $\pi$. If it wasn't than we were unable to calculate $\pi$ ans it was non-computable.

If so, that we can't provide any examples of non-computable numbers? Is that right?

The only thing that we can say is that these numbers are exist in many, but we can't point to any of them. Right?

Comment: I can't be more precise since I don't know :) I agree that probably there can be some desriptions of non-computable numbers -- this is what my question about -- please provide some for me to feel...

Comment: Roll a ten sided die numbered 0-9 an infinite number of times.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[Chaitin's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant) is an example (actually a family of examples) of a non-computable number. It represents the probability that a randomly-generated program (in a certain model) will halt.

It can be calculated approximately, but there is (provably) no algorithm for calculating it with arbitrary precision.

Comment: It is said in preamble, that there are infinite number of Omegas. This is what your words "in a certain model" address for? So in some model it can be ONE Omega and it is both non-computable and unambiguous?

Comment: Yes. You can obviously change the probability with which a random program halts by changing the programming language or computational model you are working in.  But each language has its own associated $\Omega$.

Comment: can you provide some simple example of a language, which has specific $\Omega$?

Comment: What if we will write a program, which will generate target language programs one by one, with increasing length, then run them and wait for their termination for some amount of time, longer and longer -- would this algorithm approximate (converge) to $\Omega$? or the problem is that this algorithm itself will work longer and longer going to be infinite?

Comment: An $\Omega$ number does represent something, but not (as the WIkipedia article also says) "the probability that a randomly generated program will halt", because (1) there is not any canonical probability measure on the set of programs, and (2) the non-canonical measure used to generate a particular $\Omega$ number may not be a probability measure. I realize I am being picky about this, but it is a common point of confusion in that area.

Comment: I thought it was the sum, over all halting program-input pairs, of $2^{-\ell}$, where $\ell$ is the length of the program plus input, and so was exactly the probability that a randomly-generated program would halt, assuming an appropriate method of generating programs at random.  Not so?

Comment: @MJD: An $\Omega$ number, relative to a universal prefix-free function $U$, is exactly the measure of the set of infinite binary sequences $f \in 2^\omega$ such that there is a finite prefix of $\sigma$ of $f$ on which $U$ will halt. The measure is the usual fair-coin probability measure on $2^\omega$, which is fixed and independent of $U$.

Comment: The key points:  (1) The measure is on $2^\omega$, not on $2^{<\omega}$ or on "programs". (2) There is no useful probability measure on $2^{<\omega}$ or any countable discrete set. (3) It is not even clear what a "program" for a prefix-free universal function $U$ should be, since every string is a legal input for $U$. Is a "program" then an arbitrary string (in which case the set of programs is not prefix-free, and the infinite sum of $2^{-|p|}$ over all programs $p$ diverges) or is a "program" just an input on which $U$ halts (in which case the probability a "random program" halts is 1).

Comment: The idea behind the Wikipedia article's claim is that one might try to "randomly generate" a program by repeatedly flipping a fair coin to generate a sequence $f \in 2^\omega$ and looking to see if any finite prefix of that $f$ is in the domain of a fixed universal prefix-free function $U$. But not all $f$ may have a prefix in the domain of $U$, in which case the claim that the process generates a "random program" breaks down, and makes one realize the more fundamental question of what a "program" for a universal prefix-free function is supposed to be, if that process is going to generate one.

Comment: I don't think it's entirely Wikipedia's fault. I'm pretty sure I got the same idea directly from Chaitin.

Comment: Yeah, it is very easy to get bad ideas from Chaitin's books; he likes to use informal analogies that don't really stand up under scrutiny.

Comment: Reminder: Anyone can edit Wikipedia and make it better...

Comment: Also, although we can find it approximately, I do not believe we have found many digits.

Answer (score 97):

I haven't thought this through, but it seems to me that if you let $BB$ be the Busy Beaver function, then $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-BB(i)}=2^{-1}+2^{-6}+2^{-21}+2^{-107}+\ ...  \ \approx 0.515625476837158203125000000000006$$ should be a noncomputable real number, since if you were able to compute it with sufficient precision you would be able to solve the halting problem.

Comment: *Every* finite sequence of digits is the start of the decimal expansion of an uncountable family of non-computable numbers

Comment: I recommend to specify you refer to the "shift" function, not Rado's Sigma. Even though it does not make a difference in practice, of course.

Comment: "sufficient" is a subjective term. "arbitrary" might be more appropriate - (I'm no expert though).

Comment: "Sufficient" is not a subjective term; it is a mathematical term of art with a specific technical meaning.

Comment: While it's true that "sufficient" is a technical term and not necessarily incorrect, I believe "arbitrary" is more appropriate here. In order for a number to be computable, it needs to be able to be specified with arbitrary precision. "Sufficient" implies some threshold that you must cross. "Arbitrary" implies that that threshold is infinite.

Answer (score 44):

Any language can be turned into a number, by setting the $i^{th}$ decimal to 1 if the $i^{th}$ word is in the language, and to 0 otherwise. So we can build for instance the number $H$, which describes the halting problem and is therefore uncomputable.

Comment: Would this example be more or less equivalent to the busy beaver example given by MJD?

Comment: Yes it is more or less the same idea up to encoding, which is basically *the* reason why we can exhibit uncomputable real numbers, because  a real number can encode an undecidable language.

Comment: Love this answer.

Comment: This is hilarious and yet at the same time useless to the reader.

Comment: Can you really turn a language into a number with that procedure? I understand that you can create a string of bits that is infinite in length with this procedure. But a number with an infinite amount of bits?

Comment: Also this is not one "number". You can arrange the words in any order you want. So this gives an infinite number of strings of bits that you can't compute.

Comment: @giusti I assumed a standard order, typically order by length then lexicographically. Otherwise, you need orders so that the ith word is computable, if you want to obtain an uncomputable number. If you don't make this hypothesis, you can choose an ordering that would give you the number 0.101010101.... (and as you see the digits are after the decimal point, answering your first question)

Answer (score 8):

I usually consider the function $f(n)=1$ if the $n^{th}$ computer program halts with input $0$ and $f(n)=0$ otherwise. The real number $r=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} f(n)\times 2^{-n}$ must be non-computable, otherwise you would be able to solve the halting problem.

Note: in order to accept this argument you must accept that there is a bijection between natural numbers and computer programs, which can be easily done by assigning values to the symbols used to write programs.

Answer (score 2):

Examples of uncomputable numbers, like the one clearly presented by Luis Fonsera, seem to assume that the halting of any particular Turing machine can be determined (by some other Turing machine ?). Is this always true? It not then for some values of n, Fonsera's function f(n) might not be determined and so the uncomputable number r is undetermined. An example might be a Turing machine that searches for violations of the Goldbach conjecture. Another could be a Turing machine, T, that searches through ratios of two  rational numbers to see if it can find one that is squareroot of 2. We know that this programme wil never halt but I am at a loss to see how a Turing machine could come to show this just by examining the programme of machine T. Are some mathematical truths like the irrationality of squareroot 2  uncomputable?

Answer (score 2):

Most finite strings of digits have high Kolmogorov complexity (Li & Vitanyi, 1997). This means they can not be produced by a Turing machine much smaller than the length of the string itself. There is a counting argument for this, which (overly simplified) says that there are less strings with length n-1 than there are with length n. If this is also the case for infinite strings (which I assume, but don't remember) it follows that most real numbers are uncomputable.

Li, Ming; Vitányi, Paul (1997). An Introduction to Kolmogorov Complexity and Its Applications. Springer.

Comment: You can show that there are uncountably many uncomputable real numbers more directly - there are only countably many Turing machines, so there are only countably many computable numbers, so there are uncountably many remaining real numbers that aren’t computable.