# Smallest Subset of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ Closed under Typical Operations

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Let $S$ denote the smallest subset of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ which includes $1$, and is closed under addition, multiplication, reciprocation, and the function $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \mapsto x^y.$

**Questions:**

**1.** Do either $S$ or its elements have an accepted name?

**2.** Where can I learn more about the set $S$ and it elements? *(Reference Request)*

**3.** Do there exist positive, real algebraic numbers which are not in $S$?

**4.** Are either $e$ or $\pi$ elements of $S$?

**What I Already Know:**

By the [Gelfond-Schneider Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), $S$ includes some transcendental numbers, like $2^{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Seems like this set should be countable.

Comment: @Jihad, it certainly is. That doesn't tell us much, though, since the set of algebraic numbers is also countable.

Comment: Do you know any number that does not belong to this set?

Comment: @Jihad, I suppose that any incomputable would not belong to $S,$ and [there exist incomputable numbers that can be defined explicitly](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462790/are-there-any-examples-of-non-computable-real-numbers). Although my knowledge of computability theory is sufficiently poor that I am not 100% certain of this statement. More interestingly perhaps, I have hunch that $e$ and $\pi$ do not belong to $S$, and that there might exist a fifth-degree polynomial (or higher) over $\mathbb{R}$ with a solution that does not belong to $S$.

Comment: I might add another question: is $S$ closed under subtraction (when the difference is positive)?

Comment: Just a question: what tells you that this characterization determines $S$? As inclusion is not a total order...

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, in any partially ordered set $P$, every subset $A$ of $P$ has at most one minimum element (but may have many "minimal" elements). So let $P$ denote the poset $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}_{>0}),\subseteq).$ Let $A$ denote those elements of $P$ that are closed under the relevant operations. Then $A$ has at most one least element. Regarding existence of a minimum element, it can be constructed as $\bigcap A$.

Comment: S is a subset of the positive "elementary-logarithmic" or "closed-form" numbers, as defined by Chow.  (http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)  So his paper proves, assuming Schanuel's conjecture, that the positive roots of $2x^5-10x+5$ are not in S.

Comment: @EricWofsey, if S is closed under subtraction it would include $2^\sqrt{2}-1$, and that seems unlikely.

Comment: Could we build this set by transfinite recursion and then study its properties (like for the Borel Hierarchy)?