# what is actually a "definable" real number?

Tags: computability

Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number) that a definable (real) number is a number "that can be uniquely specified by its description". I naïvely thought that this was the same as "a number which may be computed", but [elsewhere in math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/462790/89) I found out that it is not the case, because for example numbers related to Chaitin's $\Omega$ are definable but not computable. Could someone explain me what a *specification* is, then? I always thought that $\Omega$ was a probability value, which was not a real specification.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numb) question has some valuable insight into the subtleties of the notion of a "definable" real number.

Comment: As they say in that article, that's just an informal definition.  In particular, as you point out, "specification" requires definition.  The article goes on to give some concrete instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Definable" is always relative to some particular language the definition is expressed in.

A number is *definable* if there is a property expressed in that language that is satisfied for that number but by no other numbers.

There is no particular expectation that the language we use for the definition is "executable" enough to pinpoint the number with any particular precision. As one example, we can consider definitions in the full first-order language of set theory, where
$$ (x=1\land\text{the Riemann Hypothesis is true})\lor(x=-1\land\text{the Riemann Hypothesis is false})$$
can be expressed as a perfectly good property that defines a nonzero integer $x$ -- but we don't even know the sign of the number that is defined.

**Chaitin's constant** is actually not a single constant but depends on selecting a representation of Turing machines first. Slightly simplified, once we have selected an enumeration $T_n$ of Turing machines, we get a Chaitin constant
$$ \Omega = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \begin{cases} 2^{-n} & \text{if }T_n\text{ terminates} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
which again is a perfectly good *definition* (whether a given Turing machine terminates is a *well-defined* property), but we cannot *compute* the constant because whether a given Turing machine terminates is not *computable*.

(This can *also* be interpreted as a probability: Go through all of the Turing machines in sequence, flipping a coin for each and select the first machine where you get tails; what is the probability that this randomly chosen machine will terminate? But being a probability has, in itself, no bearing on whether the number is well-defined and/or computable).

Answer (score 2):

The definable numbers depend on how one defines them. Since "the least positive integer not specifiable in fewer than twelve words" is an eleven-word phrase, we get something called Berry's paradox unless we recognise that the specification standard must preclude reference to itself. Formally, this separation relies on an object language and a metalanguage for talking about it, so "the least positive integer not specificable in fewer than sixteen words of that object language" can exist as a description in the metalanguage, but not in the object language; but this forces definability to be relative.

The important point is this: no matter what specification you formalise, if you're only allowed finite-length descriptions in a language with a countable alphabet, you'll only be able to define countably many things. (Roughly speaking, this is because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\aleph_0^n=\aleph_0$.) Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, you'll definitely leave out something.

Comment: Don't you mean "$\mathbb R$ is uncountable" ?

Comment: @Pece Thanks; fixed.

Comment: Be careful of the last paragraph; it's easy to infer too much; I think the potential problem is basically another form of Skolem's paradox where you conflate internal and external properties. See [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084138/is-it-possible-that-every-set-can-be-specified) for references on how it is possible that you can specify not just every individual real number, but in fact every set!

Comment: I know of Berry's paradox, but since it deals with a metalanguage I did not think that it was a bona fide definition of a number. Indeed I was interested in computable numbers exactly because they are countable and so there must exist (many...) uncomputable real numbers.

Comment: @mau As I mentioned, it's only valid if you make succinct definability relative to a non-self-referential choice of specification. The point was to show that definability is relative, but will apply only to countably many numbers, just like computability does.

Answer (score 2):

"Definable" as a very precise meaning. Given a structure $M$ on a first-order language $\mathcal L$, an element $a\in M$ is definable if and only if there exists a formula $\varphi(x)$ in one variable such that
$$ M \models \forall x, \varphi(x) \leftrightarrow (x=a)$$

In particular "definable" is always relative to the language of specification. For example, given $M$ as before, an element $a\in M$ is always definable in (the induced structure on) $M$ over the language $\mathcal L \sqcup \{c_a\}$ where the new constant $c_a$ is interpreted as $a$ (the wanted $\varphi(x)$ is just "$x=c_a$"). Even if $a$ was not definable over $\mathcal L$.

---

When saying "Is the real number $a$ definable?", it is probable that people mean: given a model $\mathcal S$ of ZFC, is (the set corresponding to) the real number $a$ (in the usual encoding of reals in ZFC) definable over the language $\{{\in}\}$?

As nobody know an explicit model of ZFC, there is a good chance that "the real number $a$" is actually already a shortcut for the formula $\varphi(x)$. To go back to your question, when people say "Chaitin's constant", they do not refer to a specific element of a God-given model of ZFC, they refer to the construction you probably know: enumerates the countably infinite Turing's machines as $m_1,\dots$ and affect the value $t_i=0$ if $m_i$ terminates or $t_i=1$ otherwise then creates the number $\sum_{i=1}^\infty t_i10^{-i}$. All of that is completely expressable in the language $\{{\in}\}$ under the axioms of ZFC. In particular, what is bothering you is the "if $m_i$ terminates", but termination of a Turing machine is a property that can be encoded into ZFC once the notion of Turing machine is encoded into ZFC. (ZFC would be making a poor job as a foundation of mathematics if such things was not expressable.)